# Destructor for template class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have template class. One of the parameters is either `char*` or `std::string`. So I have to delete `char*`, and don`t delete`std::string`. I have no idea what I should do.

```
template <typename T>
class Discipline
{
public:
    unsigned int getLectureHours() const { return lecture_hours; }

    unsigned int getTotalHours() const { return total_hours; }

    unsigned int getPracticalHours() const { return practical_hours; }

    unsigned int getSelfHours() const { return self_hours; }

    T getName() const { return name; }

    Date& getDate() const { return date; }

    Discipline() : date(1,1,2000), name("Math"), total_hours(10), lecture_hours(4), practical_hours(4), self_hours(2) {}

    Discipline(Date* tdate, T& tname, int& t1, int& t2, int& t3) : date(*tdate), name(tname), total_hours(t1), lecture_hours(t2), practical_hours(t3), self_hours(t1-t2-t3){}

    Discipline(const Discipline<T>& other)
    {
        *this = other;
        name = "def";
    }

    Discipline<char*>& operator=(const Discipline<char*>& param)
    {
        if (this != &param)
        {
            this->name = new char[strlen(param.name)+1];
            strcpy(this->name, param.name);
            this->date = param.date;
            this->total_hours = param.total_hours;
            this->lecture_hours = param.lecture_hours;
            this->self_hours = param.self_hours;
            this->practical_hours = param.practical_hours;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Discipline<std::string>& operator=(const Discipline<std::string>& param)
    {
        if (this != &param)
        {
            // this->name = "";
            // this->name += "def";
            this->date = param.date;
            this->total_hours = param.total_hours;
            this->lecture_hours = param.lecture_hours;
            this->self_hours = param.self_hours;
            this->practical_hours = param.practical_hours;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~Discipline<char*>() {  delete[] name; }

private:
    Date date;
    T name;
    unsigned int total_hours;
    unsigned int lecture_hours;
    unsigned int practical_hours;
    unsigned int self_hours;
};
```

Comment: You don't need a template class for that. Just make the name member an std::string always and accept a const std::string& as the constructor argument. That way, if your construcor is given a const *char it will implicitly be converted to an std::string.

Comment: Great. Solved for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is explicit specialization. In the implementation, you can go like

```
template<>
Discipline<string>::~Discipline(){}

template<>
Discipline<char*>::~Discipline(){
    delete[] name;
}
```

This can be even done flexible:

```
template<class T>
Discipline<T>::~Discipline(){}

template<>
Discipline<char*>::~Discipline(){
    delete[] name;
}
```

This variant would call delete on the class over `char*` and do nothing within the destructor in every other case, if you plan on adding more specializations in the future.

You might want to read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

(Just to give an answer to the question as stated. Of course, the comment by antred is the actual solution.)

Answer (score 0):

One variant is to add a simple static method , say DeleteTheString, with two argument overloads. Then you just call with your templated type value and let the compiler decide.

Another variant is to wrap the char* in a unique_ptr[], so it deletes itself. You could do that dynamically by having a little adaptor class SafeStore has member `typedef std::string as`, while SafeStore has the `typedef std::unique_ptr<char[]> as`.